# Visual Studio Native Testing: Writing to a file after all tests have run

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I use the CppUnitTestFramework of Visual Studio 2015 to run a number of tests on my C++ code, which is working. However, after all tests have run I want to write some results into a file. I tried the following approach via TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP:

```
TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP(CleanUp) {
  std::ofstream outFile("compare.html");
  outFile << "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/></head><body><table>";

  //Write some stuff to outFile
  ...

  outFile << "</body></html>" << std::endl;
  outFile.close();
}
```

However, the file "compare.html" is not created anywhere. When I use TEST_METHOD_CLEANUP instead, it's working, but writes after every test, which is not intended. So, can I write to a file somehow from TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP?

Comment: Sounds like you should try something like TEST_CLEANUP

Comment: @ChristopherGallé Like I wrote, the cleanup method for class, i.e., TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP is not working. I also tried the module cleanup TEST_MODULE_CLEANUP which is also not working. The remaining cleanup TEST_METHOD_CLEANUP works fine but runs after every test. A simple TEST_CLEANUP does not exist.

Comment: Do you have the test class named "CleanUp" in your project?

Comment: @ChristopherGallé My test class is defaultly named UnitTest1, CleanUp is the name of the cleanup method, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694604.aspx#BKMK_Initialize_and_cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Actually, you code works fine and creates a file. See example:

```
TEST_CLASS(Example)
{
public:
    TEST_METHOD(ExampleTest)
    {
        // A test
    }

private:
    TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP(ExampleCleanUp) 
    {
        std::ofstream outFile("compare.html");
        outFile << "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/></head><body><table>";

        outFile << "</body></html>" << std::endl;
        outFile.close();
    }
};
```

Comment: I just tried your code example and just copied it into a new native unit test. Unfortunately, the result remains the same and no file appears in my case. But it's good to know that the code should work even if, in my case, it doesn't. Unfortunately, I have no idea what could affect the file writing.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's might be too late, but the answer to your question yes you can, but.

The following experiment within Visual Studio 2017 CE :

```
TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(ClassInitialize)
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage("In Test Dir Listing Class Initialize");
        Logger::WriteMessage(std::experimental::filesystem::current_path().string().c_str());
        ... 
    }
```

gave following output:

```
[dd.mm.2020 00:00:14 Informational] In Test Dir Listing Class Initialize
[dd.mm.2020 00:00:14 Informational] C:\Users\user_name\source\repos\UnitTest1\Debug
```

So you are initializing tests within your debugger working directory, but
the same logging in Cleanup class

```
TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP(ClassCleanup)
        {
            Logger::WriteMessage("In Test Dir Listing Class Cleanup");
            Logger::WriteMessage(std::experimental::filesystem::current_path().string().c_str());
            ...
        }
```

Resulted in:

```
[dd.mm.2020 00:00:15 Informational] In Test Dir Listing Class Cleanup
[dd.mm.2020 00:00:15 Informational] F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE
```

I.e. the working directory of the class Cleanup is not the one could generally expect to see.

Thus, if you want to make writing of the data into some specific file you should arrange proper full path specification. Or save working path in class Initialization and use it during cleanup procedures.